# Javascript New Date returning me Invalid Date when I passed the date as "21-04-2017 20:34:30 UTC +05:30"

Tags: javascript, date

I am using angular JS, my Server returning a date like below.
When I tried to convert it to Date format it is saying "Invalid Date".
Please any suggestions?
Below is the sample of server date.

```
function runSettlement() {
    return Restangular.one('/api/GetdateofLastrun').get().then(function 
(data) {
 var serverDate = new Date(data);
Console.log(data); //Invalid Date
}
```

Here the API call returns below data from server.
21-04-2017 20:34:30 UTC +05:30

Comment: Ideally, the API on the server should emit that timestamp in standard ISO8601 format, which would be `"2017-04-21T20:34:30+05:30"`.

Comment: The error "Invalid date" means that it's an invalid date. Look up the `Date` function to see what dates are valid. `Date` cannot read your mind and convert any arbitrary date format in the world. It converts dates in a particular, predefined format.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript [Date Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) don't support that format.

I would recommend https://momentjs.com/

"Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates and times in JavaScript."

Angular directives for Moment.js can be found at: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Comment: I don't see why this answer was down voted. Especially considering it provided the documentation that the comments did not.

Comment: Not my down vote, but likely it's seen as just a recommendation to use a library that isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP. Down votes without comments are useless.